# Raspivid Overlay

Tags: camera, raspicam, software-development, raspivid

I have been struggling for the past week to come up with a method to overlay text on a Raspivid preview. I have my raspberry pi connected via HDMI and simply want to overlay sensor data (in the form of text) over the video feed in real-time. The only thing that I have come close to is being able to get the dispmanx hello_triangle overlaid over the Raspivid feed. Any help, links to other forums, or examples would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is `dispmanx hello_triangle`? Python code? Bash command?

Comment: It's a C++ code that is compiled into an executable bash file.